# Value is not changing from variable in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Hi I am trying to change the content of a file through Powershell but its not working:

```
$mf_runw_user = 'abc'
$mf_runw_pass = facter -p mf_runw_pass
$run_path = "D:\MF_Dashboard\NMFD\Runway\Web.config"
(Get-Content "$run_path").replace('"USERID" value="*"', '"USERID" value="$mf_runw_user"') | Set-Content "$run_path"
(Get-Content "$run_path").replace('"PASSWORD" value="*"', '"PASSWORD" value="$mf_runw_user"') | Set-Content "$run_path"
```

Basically I need the below output:

```
<add key="USERID" value="abc" />
<add key="PASSWORD" value="123qweasd" />
```

but i am getting this output:

```
<add key="USERID" value="$mf_runw_user" />
<add key="PASSWORD" value="$mf_runw_pass" />
```

Please Help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's wrapped in single quotes the variable isn't expanding:

Try something like:

```
(Get-Content $run_path).Replace('"USERID" value="*"', "`"USERID`" value=`"$mf_runw_user`"") | Set-Content $run_path
(Get-Content $run_path).Replace('"PASSWORD" value="*"', "`"PASSWORD`" value=`"$mf_runw_user`"") | Set-Content $run_path
```

This is just escaping the double quotes where necessary.

Using the formatting operator may also work:

```
(Get-Content $run_path).Replace('"USERID" value="*"', '"USERID" value="{0}"' -f $mf_runw_user) | Set-Content $run_path
(Get-Content $run_path).Replace('"PASSWORD" value="*"', '"PASSWORD" value="${0}"' -f $mf_runw_user) | Set-Content $run_path
```

### Note

You have `$mf_runw_user` in both replace expressions.  I think you probably want an expression for the password in the second one.

Comment: The First I tried with escape sequence and it worked. Thanks @steven